# Laptop only displays on external monitor, even after screen was replaced

Tags: hardware-failure, laptop-display

I have an HP Pavilion G6. The screen (LED) doesn't work, but it displays fine on an external monitor with HDMI or VGA. The screen was obviously cracked so I got a new one. After replacing it, the screen was still black, so I replaced the monitor cable. Still nothing.

There's nothing at all on the screen, even when shining a light behind it. I'm assuming it can't be the GPU since it's displaying fine externally.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Which monitor cable? I assume the one of the integrated LED screen right? It sounds like a bad connection somewhere but I doubt anyone can pin it down without seeing the laptop.

Comment: Yeah, the cable connecting the laptop screen to the main board. I can take a picture if you want, but I've looked over it several times and I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: I had the problem with a Toshiba I worked on. It had a cracked screen, so I replaced it, and it did not work, though it did before. Took it apart again, which I was getting real good at it by this time since I was looking for other issues to remedy the problem, to no avail. So I took it apart for the sole purpose of removing the connectors that I removed the first time, and reconnect them again. That was the problem, me, it worked again after I reassembled the unit. Can never be too careful.